# Understanding a problem in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can someone here help me fill in the gaps of my understanding for this problem? I would appreciate it.

**Problem:** If $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$, prove that the ring $R=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(f)}$ has finitely many distinct ideals. How many distinct ideals does it have?

**Teacher's explanation:** $$R=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(f)} \longleftarrow \frac{J}{(f)}$$ means that $J \supseteq (f).$

*She mentioned that $(u \cdot g) = (g)$, but I don't see how.*

Now, $\frac{(g)}{(f)}$ where $(g) \supseteq (f)$, implies that $f \in (g)$. Thus $f$ is a multiple of $g$ and $g|f$. Thus $g$ is a monic divisor of $f$. Note that $f=c(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$ by the Linear Factorization Theorem. Now we count the monic divisors of $f$, which turns out to be:
$$ 1, (x-x_1), \ldots, (x-x_n)$$ and all products of the linear factors. Thus there are $2^n$ distinct ideals.

**My questions:**
What does $R=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(f)} \longleftarrow \frac{J}{(f)}$ mean? Why is $(u \cdot g) = (g)?$ How does counting the monic divisors of $f$ correlate with the number of distinct ideals?

Thanks.

Comment: One fact that might be useful in understanding this proof is: The ideals of $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(f)}$ are in one-to-one correspondence (i.e., there are exactly as many as in) with ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ containing $(f)$.  In general this is written as: If $R$ is a ring and $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal, then the ideals of $R/I$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the ideals of $R$ containing $I$.

Comment: As a follow up to my last comment, so if you want to know how many ideals $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(f)}$ has, you can check how many ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ containing $(f)$ there are, and that's enough since there are the same number for both.

Comment: @user46944 OK. Is the solution in my post complete? How can I fill in the gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion of your solution is wrong: if $f(x)=x^3$, then I don't think we have $2^3=8$ ideals, but we certainly have $4$: $(1)$, $(x)/(x^3)$, $(x^2)/(x^3)$, and $(x^3)/(x^3)=(0)$. Why so? We have to count how many divisors has $f$. Or if $f(x)=(x-a_1)^{k_1}\cdots(x-a_r)^{k_r}$ with $k_1+\cdots+k_r=n$, then the number of divisors is $(k_1+1)\cdots(k_r+1)$ and $(k_1+1)\cdots(k_r+1)\le2^n$ with equality iff $r=n$.

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain the last sentence of your answer in more detail, because I'm not quite sure I follow.

Comment: @Anonymous The number of divisors is easy to count: it's exactly the same as for integers. For instance, if $p$ is a prime number, then $p^i$ has exactly $i+1$ divisors, and this extends easily to a product of primes. The second assertion: one can prove by induction that $m+1<2^m$ for all $m\ge 2$. Of course, $m+1=2^m$ iff $m=1$. (One considers $m\ge 1$.)

Comment: Hmm. How does $m+1 \le 2^m$ extend to $(k_1+1)\cdots(k_r+1) \le 2^n,$ when the left hand side is not $n+1$, but a product of terms instead??

Comment: @Anonymous Just multiply $k_i+1\le 2^{k_i}$ for all $i$ and recall that $\sum k_i=n$.

Comment: Your comments are helpful. Lastly, "with equality iff $r=n$". How?

Comment: @Anonymous If $\prod_{i}(k_i+1)=2^n$ then all inequalities $k_i+1\le 2^{k_i}$ are equalities, so $k_i=1$ for all $i$.